# How to make an application server on Websphere dependent on another application server, so that it starts and stops together?

Tags: websphere

I have 2 application servers say server1 and server2 created in my Websphere. I want to make the server2 dependent on server1 so that whenever I start server1, server2 also gets started and when am stopping server1, server2 also gets stopped.

Is there any configuration in Websphere to achieve this? If not can this be done using Custom services for application server?

Answer (score 0):

u want to do the operation only through admin console or not? If not, you can just program a little customized script in which start/stop both server1 and server2 together.